# HTML data from Beautiful Soup needs formatting

Tags: python, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I have a Test Report file from Nose in html format. I would like to extract some parts of the text out of it in Python. I will be sending this in an email in the message part.

I have the following sample:

```
<table>
        <tr>
            <th>Class</th>
            <th class="failed">Fail</th>
            <th class="failed">Error</th>
            <th>Skip</th>
            <th>Success</th>
            <th>Total</th>
        </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Regression_TestCase</td>
                <td class="failed">1</td>
                <td class="failed">9</td>
                <td>0</td>
                <td>219</td>
                <td>229</td>
            </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><strong>Total</strong></td>
            <td class="failed">1</td>
            <td class="failed">9</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>219</td>
            <td>229</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

If i open the file in the browser the formatting looks like this for the text i want: This is the text I would like to extract from the html file.

```
    Class             Fail Error    Skip    Success     Total
Regression_TestCase     1    9       0      219         229
```

Using BeautifulSoup4 in Python27 I have managed to extract the following:

```
[<th>Class</th>, <th class="failed">Fail</th>, <th class="failed">Error</th>, <th>Skip</th>, <th>Success</th>, <th>Total</th>]

[<td>Regression_TestCase.RegressionProject_TestCase2.RegressionProject_TestCase2</td>, <td class="failed">1</td>, <td class="failed">9</td>, <td>0</td>, <td>219</td>, <td>229</td>, <td><strong>Total</strong></td>, <td class="failed">1</td>, <td class="failed">9</td>, <td>0</td>, <td>219</td>, <td>229</td>]
```

My code is as follows:

```
def extract_pass_summary_from_selenium_report():
    html_report = open(r"C:\test_runners\selenium_regression_test_5_1_1\ClearCore 501 - Regression Test\TestReport\SeleniumTestReport.html",'r').read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html_report, "html.parser")

    print soup.find_all('th')

    print soup.find_all('td')
```

How can I just extract the text and keep the formatting like this:?

```
    Class             Fail Error    Skip    Success     Total
Regression_TestCase     1    9       0      219         229
```

Thanks, Riaz

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can solve it with `BeautifulSoup` alone, but I'd use [`pandas`](http://pandas) and it's [`pandas.read_html()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_html.html) to parse the HTML table into a convenient dataframe:

```
from StringIO import StringIO

import pandas as pd

data = """
<table>
        <tr>
            <th>Class</th>
            <th class="failed">Fail</th>
            <th class="failed">Error</th>
            <th>Skip</th>
            <th>Success</th>
            <th>Total</th>
        </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Regression_TestCase</td>
                <td class="failed">1</td>
                <td class="failed">9</td>
                <td>0</td>
                <td>219</td>
                <td>229</td>
            </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><strong>Total</strong></td>
            <td class="failed">1</td>
            <td class="failed">9</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>219</td>
            <td>229</td>
        </tr>
    </table>"""

df = pd.read_html(StringIO(data))
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
[                     0     1      2     3        4      5
0                Class  Fail  Error  Skip  Success  Total
1  Regression_TestCase     1      9     0      219    229
2                Total     1      9     0      219    229]
```

Comment: Thanks, can i replace data with the path to the report html file e.g. c:\testreport.html because I will be reading from the file

Comment: @RiazLadhani replace the `StringIO(data)` part with a file object: e.g. `pd.read_html(open(path))`. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

add a function

```
def html_to_text(html):
    records = []
    for i in range(len(html)):
        html[i] = html[i].text
        records.append(html[i])
    return records
```

to call the function in your code

```
ths = soup.find_all('th')
ths = html_to_text(ths)
print(ths)
tds = html_to_text(soup.find_all('td'))
print(tds)
```